# How can I get the displayed range of an embedded Excel worksheet in a PowerPoint slide via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, data-wrangling

As the title explains, how do I gather the displayed range of an Excel OLE Object embedded in a PowerPoint slide via VBA? I've looked through the zipped files but I couldn't find anything in the .xlm files. I've noticed when you 'Edit' the OLE Object, the displayed range is captured by shaded border, see below for a picture. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE5UU.png)

I'm trying to gather this information to copy the cells in range and paste them back into the slide as ppt table objects. This is so that I can ultimately extract the data via python.

I've tried several different VBA functions including wb.Windows(1).VisibleRange.Address, wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address, wb.Windows(1).Selection.Address but none of them accurately capture just the displayed data.